# how to remove %7B on link redirect

Tags: visualforce

PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://sample-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/EmployeeSelfService/secur/forgotpassword.jsp?&un='+userContactUsername);

whenever i test it, the link becomes
https://sample-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/EmployeeSelfService/secur/forgotpassword.jsp?un=**%7B**laurennewemployee%40gmail.com**%7D**

how can i remove that %7B?? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the put method on the parameters that will ensure correct escaping:

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://sample-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/EmployeeSelfService/secur/forgotpassword.jsp');
pageRef.getParameters().put('un', userContactUsername);
```

Comment: I get this error Incompatible value type Set<String> for Map<String,String> @keith

Comment: @gelay what is the type of `userContactUsername` ? is it a simple text?

Comment: it is a set<String>

Comment: @gelay it should be a one string not multiple... in your case `un` should have only one parameter correct?

Comment: yes.. but the set has only one record.

Comment: @gelay if set has only one record then simply use String type add the value in string and pass in `pageRef.getParameters().put('un', userContactUsername);`